# GUI doesn't work with -X but works with -Y (matplotlib)

Tags: python, matplotlib, ssh, xserver

On Ubuntu 18.04 server, using the anaconda 3 python distro, I'm getting the following error when trying to plot something with matplotlib:

> Traceback (most recent call last):   File "fft_gen_3d.py", line 82, in
>   
>       plt.pcolormesh(t, f, Sxx)   File "/home/admin/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/matplotlib/pyplot.py",
>   line 3277, in pcolormesh
>       ax = gca()   File "/home/admin/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/matplotlib/pyplot.py",
>   line 984, in gca
>       return gcf().gca(**kwargs)   File "/home/admin/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/matplotlib/pyplot.py",
>   line 601, in gcf
>       return figure()   File "/home/admin/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/matplotlib/pyplot.py",
>   line 548, in figure
>       **kwargs)   File "/home/admin/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/matplotlib/backend_bases.py",
>   line 161, in new_figure_manager
>       return cls.new_figure_manager_given_figure(num, fig)   File "/home/admin/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/matplotlib/backend_bases.py",
>   line 167, in new_figure_manager_given_figure
>       canvas = cls.FigureCanvas(figure)   File "/home/admin/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/matplotlib/backends/backend_qt5agg.py",
>   line 24, in **init**
>       super(FigureCanvasQTAgg, self).**init**(figure=figure)   File "/home/admin/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/matplotlib/backends/backend_qt5.py",
>   line 234, in **init**
>       _create_qApp()   File "/home/admin/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/matplotlib/backends/backend_qt5.py",
>   line 125, in _create_qApp
>       raise RuntimeError('Invalid DISPLAY variable') RuntimeError: Invalid DISPLAY variable

All of the solutions online simply use the line:

> plt.switch_backend('agg')

However this doesn't work for me. What DOES work is ssh'ing in with -Y instead of -X. What's going on here?

Comment: Not that some distros, e.g. Debian, change the security defaults. So please specify which one you're using.

Comment: Ubuntu 18.04 server. Edited the original post too. Thanks.